# Kubernetes: What is the significance of "storage" field in a block Persistent Volume?

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-storage, persistent-volumes, kubernetes-statefulset

#### Scenario

I have a PersistentVolume with `volumeMode`as `Block`. It is defined as:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: block-vol
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  local:
    path: /dev/sdb # this path on the host specified below is used as a device mount
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - <my-host>
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: block-storage
  volumeMode: Block
```

When I mount this on a `statefulset` with a `VolumeClaimTemplate`, I specify it's `storage` field as `1Gi`. However, when exec'd in to the deployed pod, I see that the block size more than `1Gi` (It is the actual size of that device on physical machine)

`StatefulSet` YAML:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  serviceName: "nginx"
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: k8s.gcr.io/nginx-slim:0.8
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: web
        volumeDevices:
        - name: rawdev0
          devicePath: /dev/kdb0
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: rawdev0
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      storageClassName: block-storage
      volumeMode: Block
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi
```

I have used `blockdev` to find the size of block in bytes:

```
root@nginx-0:/# ls -lhrt /dev/kdb0 
brw-rw----. 1 root disk 8, 16 Jan 13 19:49 /dev/kdb0

root@nginx-0:/# blockdev --getsize64 /dev/kdb0 
536870912000 #size of block in bytes
```

#### Question

What does the `storage` field signify in this case?

Comment: Hey, do u need to know what does storage spec means on both examples? I think the meaning of storage is regarding to use local capacity you have available at the moment to request the block volume. Let me know if we are in the same page.

Comment: @HugoLesta: I did not understand what you meant by - `I think the meaning of storage is regarding to use local capacity you have available at the moment to request the block volume`. Could you elaborate more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kubernetes can't do much about the storage size for [local volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#local). The admin that created the `PersistentVolume` must set a proper size, for granular sizing he/she should probably create its own partition instead of mapping the local volume to a directory.

The storage size in the `PersistentVolumeClaim` is a *request* so that the app at least get a volume of that size.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, the physical block at `/dev/sdb` on the host should be tuned for storage. Is that right?

Comment: yes, that partitions size should be reflected in the `PersistentVolume` to get a good match between `PersistentVolume` and a requesting `PersistentVolumeClaim`

Comment: Usually when a device is used as local volume, the app can consume the whole volume.

Comment: `Usually when a device is used as local volume, the app can consume the whole volume` - thanks. And specifying storage capacity in PV doesn't change this. Right?

Comment: No, but it change what apps that can use the PV, only apps with a PVC that requests smaller or equal size than the PV can be scheduled to use it.